# Which is better 1Table 150,000,000,000 rows or 5000 TABLES with 300,000 rows

Tags: mysql, database

> **Would spreading the workload vertically across many rows increase
>   performance beyond splitting the workload horizontally across many
>   tables???**

- **So 1 TABLE with 150,000,000,000 rows and 6 Columns**

table1(item_id,cat_id,note) 
The NOTE column will store a non repeating INT that will constantly be changing.

The standard way.
 VS

- **5000 TABLES with 300,000 rows and 1,000 columns.**

table1(id,cat_id,item_1,item_2,item_3,...item_999) table2(table1_id,id,cat_id,item_1000,item_1001,item_1002,...item_1998) 

...
table5000(table1_id,id,cat_id,item_499000,item_499001,item_499002,...item_500000)

The column itself will define every category the item is in.
The Row will define every item in that category.
NOTE from above: will be placed in the intersected cell.

Which is better? Why? LINKS if possible

- Is there a huge performance lag when searching multiple tables versus one single one?

Comment: Just to clarify: you have 1000 columns per table?

Comment: There's something wrong with your design if you need so many columns. They should almost certainly be rows in a relation table, not separate columns.

Comment: Are these *dense* or *sparse* columns?

Comment: i think you need to carefully studdy the design here, this sounds nightmareish. hopefully, with more detail, we can sort this out. but for now, it just feels bad :(

Comment: my comment above withstanding, this is actually a great question :-). it really will open the floodgates to the old `ask 2 men in a room for an opinion and you'll get 3` conundrum. i'd love to see how this develops, if you are able to supply enough info (and have enough patience). my #1 suggestion would be to make a brief edit to the question to describe the core usecase for the tables as well as a ccouple of typical examples of light, medium and heavy duty instances of the data

Comment: Why did you initially decide to separate the categories between those that have no space in the name (i.e., Single) and those with at least 1 space (i.e., Multi)?  (That is the only difference right? 1 word or more than 1 word in the title? Or did you divide the categories by rate of growth, where it happens that categories without spaces grow slower than ones with spaces)

Comment: @AgRizzo I am not entirely sure if I needed the Multiple categories yet. I was designing for a higher traffic user base and wanted lower processing load on the server. Instead of grabbing multiple rows and calculating order for every request for Multiple SINGLEs I would merge the request and store for later use as MULTI.

Comment: @jerdiggity Yes, I have 1000 columns per table. And about 500 tables so far. I am not seeing another way to solve this problem yet.

Comment: @user2864740 I not completely familiar with the terms but I think mostly dense. Each cell will have a # between 0 - 500000.

Comment: @Barmar If I switch the Items titles to rows and have the categories as column names as expected then my table count will exceed 1000+. That is a single language we are want to add additional languages which is more tables, if I stick to Vice Versa then I can add them as rows.

Comment: You apparently don't understand the concept of a relation table. You don't need thousands of tables. Google "sql many-to-many".

Comment: @Barmar Is performance truly gained by spreading the information vertically on a single table than spreading the information into different tables tables and reducing the row size? as stated above...

Comment: It all depends on how the table will be used. From there you'll need to work out how you will index them. Very complicated question. But if you'll only be querying against 1 column for example, performance actually won't be a problem with 1000 columns and would be faster since your index will be smaller.

Comment: @uptownhr I would be querying chunks of 250 items or more. Example Items number 1-250 in a single category. I was thinking instead of taxing a two single columns (cateID,itemID) I would call cate ROW with values =< 250 and simply join the (1000+) tables...

Comment: I'm concerned about your design. With not thinking too much you should normalize your database better. I've worked in many big systems, I mean really big systems and very few of then reached the mark of 4k tables and that big ones only because it started without proper normalization. And if your database goes bigger as this you should probably be concerned in changing it to one more robust on as Oracle, IBMDB2 or MS SQL Server. If I was the one to decide for a DB that size I would choose Oracle, I find it is a better bet in terms of clustering, scaleability and for enterprise applications

Comment: Let's talk about your data and clarify a few things here. So you have 500k items and 300k in categories right now? And each item also has 1k in attributes that will connect to another table? Can you give us a sample subset of how one row of a query you will run look like? For example,

[item_id,cat_id,col1.a,col1.b,col2.a,col2.b,...] does this look about right?

Comment: @uptownhr Yes currently 300K will not exceed 1 Million until we add multi language support. And 500k item which will only grow about 1000 items a year. I KNOW THIS IS WRONG BUT WE ARE TEST multiple scenarios. table1(id,cat_id,item_1,item_2,item_3,...item_999) table2(table1_id,id,cat_id,item_1,item_2,item_3,...item_999) the column itself will define every category the item is in.

Comment: I cant stop thinking about what does this table with 1k columns store. Just for curiosity. I mean if get a table like that to make a process or a system or a user interface it would be a nightmare. Sorry for I not be polite about this.

Comment: @JorgeCampos NON-Repeating INT's Currently used to track data of multiple concurrent users we have working code and algorithms and now were building the database to test the codes full capabilities.

Comment: @Understood now don't tell me you have five thousand products and categories associated with it are multiple

Comment: Well @undertood i can describe **500,000 REAL items** as product can i that you can achieve through multivalued tables why you want 5000 tables?

Answer (score 1):

```
Bytes per short string column 8,000

Bytes per GROUP BY, ORDER BY 8,060

Bytes per row 8,060

Columns per index key 16

Columns per foreign key 16

Columns per primary key 16

Columns per nonwide table 1,024

Columns per wide table 30,000

Columns per SELECT statement 4,096

Columns per INSERT statement 4096

Columns per UPDATE statement (Wide Tables) 4096
```

This is the limit of mysql

```
When you combine varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, sql_variant, or CLR user-defined type columns that exceed 8,060 bytes per row, consider the following:
```

are you building real time application ?
do you have really idea about dividing relationships to tables?
do you have idea about **acid** property?
Your idea about database is wrong

YOu just need to revise design 
i am very much worry about your coding **how will you code???**

follow this steps

- get your requirements properly
- do some analysis
- and redesign your database i think you will really get good output

**Max rows i have columns with is 100 that is much more from my pointof view so i divided that columns in to 17 tables**

http://www.slideshare.net/ronaldbradford/top-20-design-tips-for-mysql-data-architects-presentation
checkout this link

Comment: Real time? Yes once database is complete. Table? yes but we are testing a new concept. ACID is a new term but have been doing the concept without knowing the acronym. NOW, how it my idea about database wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and explain from scrach why would you need 1000 columns per table?