# Individual ranking system causing Database crashes => Revert to Individual Tables?

Tags: mysql, database

I ask a similar question [(1 table 150,000,000,000 rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19716462/which-is-better-1table-150-000-000-000-rows-or-5000-tables-with-300-000-rows) now I will add some details.

- 500,000 Items
- Unlimited # Categories
- 15 Sections

The site allows users to create their own categories and place as many items into that category. Before they can add anything they must choose what section the category is best represented.

> Each of the above will have:  **id, title, description, imageURL**

I have two issues:

1. Each CATEGORY/ITEM will beable to re-arrange items/categories greatest to worst. COLUMN: **rank**
2. Users will be acknowledged for contributing most to category. COLUMN: **king**

This feature of the site is pretty simple but the ranking process is throwing me for a loop. I have tried multiple test runs cramming as much data into one table as possible but the results are **crashing** my spirits. The division of data to tables is not easy because of the individual ranking for each category.

---

The original design was to Have the above 3 and individual tables of each category/item to allow individual ranking(boost speed/performance) then:

- User contributor: **sectionID, categoryID, itemID, userID**
- Individual Rank: **categoryID/itemID, rank**

The outcome would be 150,000,000,000 tabled labyrinth. Has anyone dealt with this concept before? What is the best plan of action? Am I on the right track?

---

I just got 
[High Performance MySQL, 3rd Edition

Optimization, Backups, and Replication](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do) 
and
 [Beginning PHP and MySQL: From Novice to Professional 4th (fourth) Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00E28LUXW)
**I am not promoting or endorsing these books...**

These are the first of many steps I will be taking to tackle this design problem I face. Any comments and assistance will be appreciated. **Thoughts; Concerns??**

Comment: You're gonna need a bigger boat.

Comment: For efficiency / ease of development you could try adding a table for categories, items and users. Each category entry would be tied to a user, have an array of item id numbers (arrangeable), and then a comment type system(likely another table) for the user contribution rank. Hope this helps.